# How to track an item in non network areas using react native and php

Tags: php, gps, gsm

Good day sir/ma, I am working on a project that intends to track items in places where there is not GSM network, so I want to be able to lift the GPS coordinates of this item/s and send them to my PHP application even though the item/s might be in a place where there's no GSM reception and internet connection, please how do I go about this.

Comment: and on what device do you want to do it? if you don't have internet and you write it down on a piece of paper and then when you're at the machine with internet you type it :) describe in more detail what you want to do

Comment: if you are staying in the item area and don't have internet. On a laptop, you create applications in any technology (it can be php), enter data (or read it from GPS) and save it to a local database on your laptop. And when you are within range of the Internet - you send the collected data to the main application (if necessary)